# what is the prototype declaration for this code?

Tags: c, function, argument-passing

three functions I am calling from main to print the array

```
void display(int *q,int row,int col){
                                      //code
                                 }
void show(int(*q)[4],int row,int column){
                                       //code
                                    }
void print(int q[][4],int row,int column){
                                       //code
                                        }
```

I am calling this display(),print() and show() from main():

```
int a[3][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2};
display(a,3,4);
show(a,3,4);
print(a,3,4);
```

The three functions are printing the elements of an array with three different ways
Now I want to know what will be prototype declaration of display(),print() and show()??

Comment: `void display(int *q,int row,int col);` and `void show(int(*q)[4],int row,int column);` and `void print(int q[][4],int row,int column);`

Comment: `display(a,3,4);` --> E.g. `display(*a,3,4);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void display(int *q,int row,int col);
void show(int(*q)[4],int row,int column);
void print(int q[][4],int row,int column);
```

if you put the function definition before main function then no need of prototype declaration...